# Syncing DynamoDB with ElasticSearch for old Data

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm using this function https://github.com/bfansports/dynamodb-to-elasticsearch to sync my DynamoDB table with ElasticSearch. Unfortunately it's only processing the newly added data and Updated ones and not the previously existing rows in the table despite i chose "New and old images - both the new and the old images of the item
" in the Manage stream section.

How to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i ended up with updating the DynamoDB and that triggers the Stream so Sync between ElasticSearch and DynamoDB can be done.
This is the script that i use :

```
import json
import boto3
import random


def lambda_handler(event, context):

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('image-library')

response = table.scan(
    ProjectionExpression='#k',
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        '#k' : 'id', #partition key
    }
)

items = response['Items']

random_number = random.randint(0,1000)

for item in items:
    response = table.update_item(
        Key=item,
        UpdateExpression='SET #f = :f',
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            '#f' :'force_update'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':f' : random_number
        }

    )
```